# Can I “opt out” of Google Calendar while keeping my Gmail account?

Tags: google-calendar, apple-ical, icloud

I would like to handle invitations manually (in iCloud, actually) without any invitations, events, or *anything* showing up in my Google Calendar account.

Because if that’s the case, there *will* be a time when I click “accept” and it gets added to a calendar I don’t use.

Please do not suggest non-answers! Valid answers:

- How to disable Calendar while keeping Gmail
- Any magic solution to always mirror GCal events to iCloud
- A sourced answer that what I ask is impossible (no guesses).

Comment: It would help if your question were more clear. When you refer to "opting out" or "disabling" Google Calendar, do you mean (1) on your Mac (iCal) or (2) opting out of the service entirely, such that your Google Account does not have Google Calendar?

Comment: I mean #2. Otherwise clicking "accept" in a Google-sent calendar invitation ("by accident") would add the event to the wrong calendar.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? You can disable calendar syncing and telling us which version you are using would help us explain or refer you to the correct instructions.

Comment: I’m on Lion (10.7.3)… though I’m not entirely sure why you are asking

Answer (score 2):

While it's not possible to disable the Google Calendar portion of your Google account altogether, it's easy to remove it from OS X.

Go to the Mail, Contacts, and Calendars preference pane in System Preferences:
[image]

Then deselect Calendars from your Google account:
[image]

Voilá! No more Google Calendar in iCal.

Similarly, on iOS:

[image]

---

Updated answer:

To stop receiving email notifications from Google Calendar, go to the Settings in calendar and go to your primary calendar (it should be labeled as your email address if you haven't changed anything.) Then to to the Notifications tab and uncheck all notifications. This will prevent you from being emailed regarding any calendar activity.

[image]

Comment: While I appreciate the effort you put into this, I really do know how to add and remove accounts from my own device. It’s removing a Google app from a Google account that I fear to be impossible.

Comment: I see. Well following these steps will ensure that the concerns in your question won't happen. Your best bet is to contact Google directly. And good luck with that. ;)

Comment: It helps, but you could still click “accept” in the body of an email, or whatever, and then Google accepts the invite to your calendar.

Comment: See my updated answer to remedy your cited concern. However, it is extremely unlikely that you'll manually click "Accept" in the middle of the body of an invitation email. Additionally, you'll want to send all future emails from `calendar-notification@google.com` to spam, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Lion you can use the following solution found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16867731#16867731)

> If you subscribe to an external (e.g. Google) calendar in iCal on Lion, you can choose to have that subscription "located" on iCloud or on your Mac. If on iCloud, that (read-only) subscription will propogate to all of your other devices that are linked to your iCloud account.[snip...]

Comment: That’s not technically the solution I wanted, at all, but I think I see what you’re saying — this would have a similar effect in that at least the events added to the wrong calendar would still be visible on all my devices. Thanks.